# Which IoC containers work with Windows Store apps?

Tags: windows-store-apps, ioc-container

Which IoC containers can be used in Windows Store App projects?

Answer (score 1):

- [Hiro](https://github.com/philiplaureano/Hiro)
- [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)
- [MetroIoc](http://metroioc.codeplex.com/)
- [TinyIoc](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC/)
- [PortableIoc](http://portableioc.codeplex.com/)
- [Mugen](http://mugeninjection.codeplex.com)

Please re-use this answer to add new entries or edit existing ones.